# How to Make anypage a RSS feed Free?

Tags: rss, feed

I wanted to import this as an RSS feed on my website http://www.huffingtonpost.com/news/yoga/ but it is not an RSS feed.

Huffington post does have RSS feeds but they are so broad. I want one just about yoga. I see there are sites that do it but you have to pay for it.

I just want to get the title, small description, and link back url like most rss feeds.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2021 rss.app seems to be quite comperensive service for transforming websites to rss feeds: https://rss.app/

Deprecated information:

> I tried a few services and the best results (=ease of use and good
> looking rss feed) I got with [Kimono](http://www.kimonolabs.com). They
> support JSON, CSV and
> [RSS](https://www.kimonolabs.com/learn/rss-feeds) results or you can
> [embed](https://www.kimonolabs.com/learn/create-kimonoblock) the feed
> on your site and they even have a [Wordpress
> plugin](https://www.kimonolabs.com/learn/wordpress). Here is the API
> feed I created if you want to try (requires login):
> https://www.kimonolabs.com/apis/3qhk4fyq
>
> Other services that I quickly tried are [Feed43](http://feed43.com/)
> and [Page2rss](http://page2rss.com/). Those seem usable, but also a
> bit difficult to use or limited in features.
> [Superfeedr](http://www.superfeedr.com/) also allows
> [subscribing](http://documentation.superfeedr.com/subscribers.html) to
> html elements, but requires more skill to get something working out of
> it.
>
> All of those services are free or offer free plans with limited features.

Comment: 2016-02-29 kimono has joined Palantir (source: http://www.kimonolabs.com/)