# Create RSS feed of a website that does not have RSS button

Tags: web, rss

Most websites I visit have RSS feed where you can subscribe to.

I went to one website, http://www.metopera.org, and they do not have any options for creating an RSS feed.

Specifically, I would like to pull from http://www.metopera.org/metopera/news/index.aspx?nav=top

1 -  Is it possible to create RSS subscription for a website that doesn't have this option

2 -  If it is possible, then how do I create the RSS subscription. Is there a website where I copy and paste the URL and it gives me the RSS url?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582460/how-to-make-anypage-a-rss-feed-free

Comment: Maybe it's best to actually ask them to add an RSS feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up right-clicking the page, selecting "View Source", and search for "RSS". Sure enough, it gave RSS url that I was able to use.