# extract rss from sites without rss

Tags: rss, web-crawler

I am trying to find a program (open source or paid, I would like to see what works) that can produce an RSS feed from sites that don't have RSS. I've tried sites like [feedity](https://feedity.com/) and [page2rss](http://page2rss.com/) but they don't really work that well and most importantly they require that I specify, pages, titles, summary etc in order to work.

I am looking for something that maybe for instance, produces the XML file of the website and after that point it continues to trigger this every time I call it (let's say a every 20min cron) and gives me the latest posts.

I don't won't it to be necessarily about news sites but in general.

I am trying to create a stream, but crawling sites without rss is not an option, and I am looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

[Kimono](https://www.kimonolabs.com/learn/rss-feeds) might work for you, see my answer here: [How to Make anypage a RSS feed Free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582460/how-to-make-anypage-a-rss-feed-free)
It returns JSON, CSV or RSS formatted output.

Also, if you are able to hack some Java code, [Boilerpipe](https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) is very smart at extracting articles from web pages. There is even an [API demo](http://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/).